# Combinatorics with expected value and average of the results

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, expected-value, average, law-of-large-numbers

I was faced with a task of calculating the average value of numbers that satisfy the following rule.

We have an infinite sequence of numbers $num$. Also we have a sequence $f$ with values *f(a)* = *b - a - 1*, where *b* is the first index $i$ where *num[i] < num[a]* and *b > a*. For example, for first numbers of sequence *num = {3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 0, ...}*, *f = {1, 0, 2, 1, 0, #, ...}*.

*(1 = 3 - 1 - 1,*

*0 = 3 - 2 - 1,*

*2 = 6 - 3 - 1,*

*1 = 6 - 4 - 1,*

*0 = 6 - 5 - 1,*

*# = c - 6 - 1*), where *c* - index of {next number *< 0*}.

The minimum value is not defined due to the infinity of the sequence. The task is to calculate the average of numbers of the array *f*.

I calculated the expected value for each value, due to the fact that the probability of getting a number that is less than the given one is *0.5*. This means that the probability of getting *f (a) = 0* is *0.5*. The probability of getting *f (a) = 1* is *0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25*, and so on. And the expected value is *1*. Next, I used the law of large numbers and found that the average value that *f(a)* gets *= 1*, just like the average value of all values **f* = 1*.

However, when I decided to program the algorithm for finding the average value through ordinary search with *Python*, I got that the average value of the array increases with an increase in the number of terms in the sequence, and it is much greater than *1*. (for *k = 1,000,000*,  *avg(f)* = *12*).

What is the correct value for this task - average = *1* or greater value that the program is aiming for? Should I look for an error in the code or there is a mistake in the calculations above?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question and definition of $f$. Can you explain how you got the numbers in your example in detail? For example, there’s no “endless sequence” in your example, and does $\{1,0,2,1,0,\#\}$ mean $f(1)=1, f(2)=0,\dots$? What does the # mean? You say “the minimum value” is not defined due to the infinity of the sequence,” but what is the “minimum value” and again, there is no infinite sequence. And in your example, what is $f$? It is a function first (listed as a set?) and then it is a number.

Comment: By $f$ I mean an infinite sequence, by $f(i)$ - its values. I need to find the average value of the sequence $f$. ${1,0,2,1,0,#}$ - it's just an example to show how $f$ is built. I wrote $#$, because in example $0$ - minimum of this sequence, but in an infinite sequence there will be no minimum, and the value $f(i)$ will be determined for all $i$. I need to calculate the average of all elements of a sequence $f$. And yes, $f(1) = 1., ..$, because $f(1) = 3 - 1 - 1 = 1$. Here num(b) = 3, because $4 > 3$ and $1 < 3$, i.e $1$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: Sorry, this is still really confusing. You wrote: $f(a) = b - a - 1$, where $b$ is the first number $i$ where num[i] < num[a]. 

Let's try to apply this to find $f(1)$. So $f(1)$ is $b-1-1$, where “$b$ is the first number $i$ where $num[i] < num[1]$. Your detail says $b=3$.

I don’t understand how “3 is the first number $i$ where $num[i] < num[1]$.

Then you say $f(4)= 1 = 6 - 4 - 1$, so apparently $6$ is “the first number $i$ where $num[i] < num[4]$. It looks like $num[4]=2$, so why isn’t $b=3$? Also, you seem to have $a$ wrong where you work out $f(2)$.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake with $f(2)$.  “$3$ is the first number i where $num[i]<num[1]$" - here i'm meaning that $num[1] = 3, num[2] = 4, 4 > 3$;  $num[3] = 1, 1 < 3$. How we can see $num[2] > num[1]$ and $num[3] < num[1]$. That's why $b = num[3]$. $b$ - it's first index of the number, that is lower than $num[a]$. ($b > a$, of course). Sorry, it looks like I confused the concept of index with a number.

Comment: Now I see what your function $f$ is, but I’m not sure the question you are asking is well-defined. The average value of $f(a)$ depends on what the sequence $num$ is. For the sequence $num=0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,\dots$, $f(k)=0$ for all $k$, but for other sequences, the average value is positive. You seem to rely on the “fact” that the $n+1$-st integer in $num$ is less than $n$ with probability one-half. That’s not true for the sequence $num=0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,\dots$ (nor for many others). I don't know what sequence you used in your Python calculation.